# Mapping a "Name" to an Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I setup a "Name" to a column range, and I want to reference it later on:

```
Dim r As Range
r = Application.Names("Changes").Something
```

I've tried a bunch of "Something" but cannot get this right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dim r as Range
Set r = Range("Changes")
```

The 'Set' keyword is very important.

This will work for any size range, including a single cell.

Then you can access the properties and methods of your range variable 'r'.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Set r = Application.Names("Changes").RefersToRange
```

Answer (score 1):

Do either RefersTo or RefersToRange work?

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
Dim R As Range
Set R = ThisWorkbook.Names("Changes").RefersToRange
```

I think it will only work if the range is 2 cells or more. If it is one you have to do something else...don't really remember though.

Another way is as follows.

```
Sheets("Name").Range("Changes")
```